# Windows Store App Open file with DisplayApplicationPicker if not recognized

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, file-access

In my app i store some files and i open them with this code:

```
           StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;            
           StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(objectName);
            if (file != null)
            {
                // Launch the retrieved file
                bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
            }
            else
            {
                messageBox("File not found", "Attention");
            }
```

It works great for file such as PDF, XML, DOC etc but it's not working at all with file with particular extension such as XML...
I would like to open the DisplayApplicationPicker BUT only for unrecognized files:

```
            // Set the option to show the picker
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = false;

            // Launch the retrieved file
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
```

Is there a way to do this?!

Comment: Found solution!Just check the bool success!!!